# Multiple submit buttons based on dropdown choice

Tags: javascript, html, forms, drop-down-menu, submit-button

Newbie question... wondering if javascript could be the solution?

Is it possible to have a dropdown menu with a number of options.  Then, based on which option is chosen determine the action of two submit buttons?

In this case where each Submit button would link to depending on the option chosen in the dropdown... the links on each button being different?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a javascript function tied to the onClick method of your buttons.  Then inside of that function you can query the current selections of your drop down list box and perform the appropriate action?

Comment: Thank you both so much for the quick reply... are there any links to tut's / examples you could show me? Not a complete newb' but might be able to muddle through with some direction. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily with Jquery.  You would just assign the click event to the submit button after the dropdown choice is made.

Look at http://api.jquery.com/change/ add a change event handler to the drop down.  In the change event handler set up the appropriate click handler for the submit buttons.

Here is an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/24Vbr/6/

HTML

```
    <form>
      <input class="target" type="text" value="Field 1" />
        <select class="target">
          <option value="option1" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        </select>  
      <button id='button1' type="button">Button with changing click handler based on dropdown </button>
    </form>
    <div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
```

---

js

```
var onSubmit1 = function()
{
    alert('submit1');
};

var onSubmit2 = function()
{
    alert('submit2');
};



$('.target').change(function(e) {    
    var dropdown = $('.target');
    var text = $( ".target option:selected" ).text();    

    var $button1= $('#button1');
    $button1.unbind('click');

    if(text == "Option 1"){
         $button1.click(onSubmit1);
        return;
    }

   $button1.click(onSubmit2);      
});
```

Comment: Thank you both so much for the quick reply... are there any links to tut's / examples you could show me?  Not a complete newb' but might be able to muddle through with some direction.

Many thanks again!

Comment: Hi Jeffo,

Many thanks for the help here.  I can see how this would work in principal, however I can't seem to get the example to work locally.  Besides, I need to be able to do this for two, possibly three Submit buttons on the same page each linking to a different .pdf 

Will keep trying to get this example working first, but thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Well I really need to concentrate on one thing at a time... managed to get things working locally easily enough, but wondering first how to get 'Option 1' working onload.  It will only work once you've selected 'Option 2', and secondly, being able to add a second submit button with it's own click events?

Comment: Try the jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/24Vbr/6/ it makes playing with the ideas really easy.  Then you can make it work in your own project.  The reason option 1 does not work the first time is the example I gave, only assigns the click event on an option change.  To fix that just assign a click event on construction or page load.  The drop down change will still need to change the click handler based on the dropdown selection though (at least how I understand the problem)

Comment: I hope the answer has got you started in the right direction.  If so accept the answer?

Comment: Certainly did Jeffo, still trying to get option 1 to work on page load?  But really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.  Thank you!